# After importing project from eclipse to android studio , images are showing blurred

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools

My app is actually live from eclipse. When I install the app from the playstore it works good and no images are blurred. My question is why images are blurred after they are imported into android studio.

The App is installed in oreo api 26 but I'm getting following error when installed in kitkat api 19:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':easyRewardz:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zi]

Comment: post code also here

Comment: you want to see my build.gradle file @quick learner

Comment: java class where the images are used

Comment: NetworkImageView headerImage = (NetworkImageView) headerView
      .findViewById(R.id.locatestore_headericon);
    headerImage.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.img_loading);
    headerImage.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.img_loading);

Comment: i have added all images in drawable folder .

Comment: this project 3 years old now i have import in android studio if anyone know the solution please tell me.

Comment: just import manually :)

Comment: create a new project and then transfer files

Comment: ok i try this @quicklearner

Comment: i have add new images in drawable folder still images are blurred @quicklearner please help me.

Comment: did u compress them ?

Comment: Please make sure your images should be good enough to be seen in all devices

Comment: no i did not compress them

Comment: post your gradle also please

Comment: @GhostCat how can i reslove this.